# Knockout observable array within Observable array, add remove methods

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout observable array that contains another array. I am trying to get the (add/remove) methods for both arrays (CountyCollections, specialtyCollections) to work. I need to be able to add or remove only a specific CountyCollection or specialtyCollection. What changes do I need to make? Here is my viewmodel and code.

```
var initialData = {
     FirstName: "George",
     LastName: "Jettison",
     CountyCollections: [{
         applicationIdentifier: "",
         countyId: 0,
         countyCode: "01",
         countyName: "",
         specialtyCollections: [{
             applicationIdentifier: "99",
             countyCode: "03",
             specialtyId: 0,
             specialtyName: "",
             patentRegistrationNumber: ""
         }]
     }]
 };

var ResultModel = function (data) {
     var self = this;
     self.FirstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
     self.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
     self.CountyCollections = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.CountyCollections,
      function (item) {
         return item;
     }));

     self.CountyCollections.specialty = ko.observableArray([]) ;   

      var getById = function (items, id) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function (item) {
                return item.countyCode === id;
            });
        }; 

     self.addSpecialty = function() { 
         alert(self.CountyCollections()[0].specialtyCollections[0].applicationIdentifier);
         self.CountyCollections()[0].specialtyCollections.push(new specialtyCollections);};


     self.addCounty = function () {
         alert(self.CountyCollections.length);
         self.CountyCollections.push(data);
     };

     self.removeCounty = function (data) {
         self.CountyCollections.remove(data);
     };
 };

 ko.applyBindings(new ResultModel(initialData));
```

Here is my jsfiddle that is partially working: http://jsfiddle.net/CurtRabon/ntoezwuk/12/

Comment: What isn't working?  I can't understand what your fiddle is trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

- Since you are wanting to add/remove items from `specialtyCollections`, it should be observable

This can be addressed in a couple of ways. You could use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) or change your `arrayMap` processing function to convert the nested array to an observableArray

```
 function (item) {
       item.specialtyCollections = ko.observableArray(item.specialtyCollections);
       return item;
 }
```

### Adding items

- While this may be a temporary implementation detail,  `addSpecialty` should not be hardcoded to use index `0`

To add a `specialty` to the "current" parent object, you can use the fact that the context of the function (*when used within a foreach binding*) will be set for you.

```
self.addSpecialty = function () {
     this.specialtyCollections.push({
         applicationIdentifier: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
     });
 };
```

Or if you prefer, knockout will provide the element as a parameter

```
self.addSpecialty = function (data) {
     data.specialtyCollections.push({
         applicationIdentifier: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
     });
 };
```

Both of the above usages are represented in the markup by:

```
<button data-bind='click: $parent.addSpecialty'>New Specialty</button
```

### Removing items

There are many ways to achieve this functionality. In the markup you have provided `$parent.removeSpecialty` which indicates you would like the implementation to be within the object container for the given list of items. As such, you'll need to provide that function during the `arrayMap`. The binding would then become

```
<button data-bind='click: function(){$parent.removeSpecialty($data)}'>X</button>
```

Alternatively, you can provide the function at the `$root` level

```
self.removeSpecialty = function (county, item) {          
     county.specialtyCollections.remove(item)
 }
```

and supply both the necessary parameters

```
<button data-bind='click: function(){$root.removeSpecialty($parent, $data)} '>
 Remove Specialty
</button>
```